# What is the limitation on using res HSQLDB?

Tags: hsqldb

We want to access `HSQLDB Db` files `(*.data, *.properties, *.script)` from a jar file.

The res HSQLDB works fine with small size of HSQLDB DB files. It gets slower when the size of DB files get a little bigger. It dies when the file size get really big. The size of DB files in our projects is 2.1GB and it dies (see err-msg below). And we can't use the work around method to unjar these DB files into `java.io.tmpdir` because of the spec..)

Does anyone one know the size limitation on Db file size when use res HSQLDB?

```
=========== 2015-05-05T15:31:15.072-0400 SEVERE DataFileCache.open

java.io.IOException: read beyond end of file at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFileInJar.readIntoBuffer(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.persist.RAFileInJar.readInt(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.open(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.getCache(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.getCache(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.newStore(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.persist.PersistentStoreCollectionDatabase.getStore(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.Table.getRowStore(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.TableBase.isEmpty(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.TableWorks.addIndex(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.getResult(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.execute(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderText.readDDL(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.scriptio.ScriptReaderBase.readAll(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.processScript(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.persist.Log.open(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source) at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) ...
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

My first guess it is due to an integer overflow / Integer.MAX_VALUE limitation: 2^31-1 = 2147483647 bytes = 2.1 GB

Have you tried [setting](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html)

```
hsqldb.cache_file_scale = 8
```

in the  *dbname*.properties file? Note that you need to perform `SHUTDOWN SCRIPT`first before augmenting the file:

> This property can be set to 8 to increase the size limit of the .data
>   file from 2GB to 8GB. To apply the change to an existing database,
>   SHUTDOWN SCRIPT should be performed first, then the property=value
>   line below should be added to the .properties file before reopening
>   the database.
>
> hsqldb.cache_file_scale=8
>
> The property can be set with the SQL command (as opposed to changing
>   the value in the properties file) when the database has no CACHED
>   tables (e.g. a new database). (SET PROPERTY)

Comment: The answer is probably correct. But the setting is used for a connection property when a new database is created. It is not supported to be set in the .properties file.

Comment: @fredt I've updated my answer. According to the docs you can do it on an existing database if you follow the right procedure.

Comment: You quote from version 1.8 docs. For version 2.x use the property on connection URL after SHUTDOWN SCRIPT. see `SET FILES SCALE 8` http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_cache_persistence